# The injection Of A Theme App Extention Block Into A Section That Has No Objects In An Editor

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I'm creating an app similar to a whishlist in Shopify, and I want users to select products for later on a product listing page.

This is why I created an app block which allows users to do this when it's cliked.

However, I do not understand how I can integrate this block inside the `product-grid` card component of the theme using just an editor without changing a shop's code directly.

[image]

Any help is massively appreciated :-)

Comment: I'm not sure what theme are you using, but if it supports, you can create a new section in the theme editor that includes your product-grid card component and your app block. Create new section with your card component, and adding your app block (drag n drop).

Comment: This is for an app so it should work with all themes.